# I was unable to place last div in proper way. While Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

i was unable to place last div in proper way.

my output from database for query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.sub_id, b.sub_name FROM cat a, sub_cat b WHERE a.id = b.cat_id
```

will be:

```
|  id  |  name     | sub_id | sub_name                  |
|  1   | moblie    |   1    | Phone                     |
|  1   | mobile    |   2    | Mobile Phones Accessories |
|  2   | Lifestyle |   3    | Arts                      |
|  2   | Lifestyle |   4    | Books                     |
```

i want to make this structure:

```
    <div id="moblie" class="tab-pane active">
<a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=1">Phones</a>
<a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=2">Mobile Phones Accessories</a>
</div>
<div id="Lifestyle " class="tab-pane">
<a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=3">Arts</a>
<a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=4">Books</a>
</div>
```

My Original Php Code :

```
<?php $query = "SELECT a.id, a.name, b.sub_id, b.sub_name FROM cat a, sub_cat b WHERE a.id = b.cat_id";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $i=0; 
        $a=1; 
        $b=0; 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $i++;
            if($i == 1){$set = "active";}else{$set = NULL;}
            $hre=strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $row['name'])); 
            while($a == $row['id']){ $a++;?>
            <div id="<?=$hre?>" class="tab-pane <?=$set?>">
            <?php }?>
            <a href="?cat=<?=$row['id']?>&sub_cat=<?=$row['sub_id']?>"><?=$row['sub_name']?></a>
            <?php while($b == $row['id']){ $b++;?></div>
            <?php }
        }?>
```

Output I am receiving :

```
<div id="mobilephones" class="tab-pane active">
  <a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=1">Mobile Phones</a>
  <a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=2">Mobile Phones Accessories</a>
<div id="homelifestyle" class="tab-pane ">
  <a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=3">Art - Collectibles - Hobbies</a>
  <a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=4">Books - Magazines</a>
  </div></div>
```

My Idea :
as it was last while loop how can it understand upcoming value to print div.

I have tried in different ways not not found solution.Please help me out.

Note:I know how to make it with loop quires.but,I want to do it through single mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Important**
>
> Avoid using `mysql_*` functions! They are deprecated.

For your solution, you can simply use this way:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $flag = 0;
    while (false !== ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
    {
        if ($data["id"] != $flag)
        {
            if ($data["id"] != 1) echo "</div>\n";
            echo '<div id="' . $data["name"] . '" class="tab-pane', ($data["id"] == 1) ? ' active' : '', '">', "\n";
        }
        echo '<a href="?cat=' . $data["id"] . '&amp;sub_cat=' . $data["sub_id"] . '">' . $data["sub_name"] . '</a>', "\n";
        $flag = $data["id"];
    }
?></div>
```

**Output**

```
<div id="mobile" class="tab-pane active">
  <a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=1">Phone</a>
  <a href="?cat=1&amp;sub_cat=2">Mobile Phones Accessories</a>
</div>
<div id="Lifestyle" class="tab-pane">
  <a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=3">Arts</a>
  <a href="?cat=2&amp;sub_cat=4">Books</a>
</div>
```

This should probably do the trick. Let me know the results in the comments.

Comment: Actually  I had n number of rows with n number of id.

Comment: i made changes for strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $data['name'])); because of some javascript..Your code is working perfect..!

Comment: i can't understand "Avoid using mysql_* functions! They are deprecated", Do u have any better Option than mysql_* functions?

Answer (score 0):

What if you iterate over the complete results "grouping" by the category name

```
 $awesomearray=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $awesomearray[$row['name'][]=$row;
 }
```

and then iterate over the grouped array

```
foreach($awesomearray as $category=>$data) {
    echo '<div id="'.$category.'" class="tab-pane">     ';
        foreach($data as $subcategory) {
            echo '<a href="?cat='.$subcategory['id'].'&amp;sub_cat='.$subcategory['sub_id'].'">'.$subcategory['sub_name'].'</a>';
        }
    echo '</div>     ';
}
```

this doesn't deal with the 'active class', but I believe you can sort it out.

PD: if you used php-pdo_mysql instead of php-mysql you could have skipped the first part, using fetchAll and PDO::FETCH_GROUP. Give it a chance.

Comment: Need to change code $awesomearray[$row['name'][]=$row; to $awesomearray[$row['name']][]=$row; .Causing Error in script.